# How to Correctly Build a MongoDB Nested property Name using C# Driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I must be missing something blindingly obvious. Somebody please shame me;

I'm building 2.2 Aggregation queries, which aren't natively supported by the C# Linq Driver, so I'm having to build up stringified names for nested properties using dotted notation. Say I have a structure like this;

```
    db.so.insert({
    a:1,
    b:2,
    n : {
        z:4,
        x:5,
        y: {
           v:"value",
        }
    }
});
```

So to reference the "value" I would need to use the name `n.y.v` or `n[y][v]`. Now, since I'm receiving the choice of field property names for the query from the web client (`http://www.demo.org/exampleQuery?field1=n&field2=y&field3=v`) I need to construct the property names thus;

```
var fieldNameForQuery = field1+"."+field2+"."+field3;
```

I'm obviously nervous about this, so of course I'm defending against NOSQL Injection by sanitising my input parameters, but I'd much rather be using the C# driver for this instead.

I guess I'd like something like;

```
MongoDB.Driver.BuildNestedFieldName(field1, field2, field3));
```

which is basically what I've had to write myself, but it feels like a kludge, and I'd rather not maintain the responsibility for building DB safe field names this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently isn't a function to do what you are wanting.  However, if all the function does is stick "."'s in the middle, then we aren't solving an injection problem because the stuff we are inserting can't have been injected...  The injection problem would be solved by ensuring that "field1", "field2", and "field3" are valid values for field names.  Of course, there isn't much that is invalid according to http://bsonspec.org/#/specification.  The only thing we'd be checking for is that there aren't 2 null terminators in the string.  So... that doesn't leave us with much we can do.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks. So I'm sanitising field1 etc at the moment, but your comment about "there isn't much that is invalid" surprises me. Without validation and using string concatenation, I can surely inject almost anything like, '\"); db.col.remove();'

Comment: :).  Mongodb doesn't operate in the same way sql does.  You can't do that with mongodb,  so no need to worry about something like that.  The only thing you'd really need to worry about would be if you were issuing a dropCollection command and letting the user specify the collection names.  They could drop $cmd collection, etc...  However, you are issuing a query, so this isn't a problem.

Comment: Actually I'm currently building my Aggregation queries as json text and therefore I have to sanitise web inputs that go into this text. Basically it means I can write my queries in shell compatible JS and simply LoadResource() them up as a json pipeline array (as text) at runtime. That's why I'm injecting string concatenated field names "like.this.example". However, I'm starting to reconsider this approach, but the JS files are much easier to work with a development time than constructing pipeline statements with the driver. If we had proper linq support I'd rather have used that.

Comment: You mean for the aggregation framework?  I'm working on that currently, but it means rewriting a lot and then putting that on top.  Not a quick solution and we only have so much time.  Regardless, even using json files, the injection that you are worried about can't happen.  It would essentially result in an invalid aggregation query.

Comment: I take your point - I'm not going to be able to change the DB command no matter what text I feed into 'Collection.Aggregate(pipeline);' but I would easily be able to modify the pipeline, possibly to include fields or documents I'm not supposed to. If I wasn't checking substitutions for ("'$.},) and friends that is :)

Comment: That is true.  Well, as I said, we are working on linq to aggregation, but until then, you are doing the only thing you can do...

Comment: OK thanks. It is painful right now. I really don't like constructing DB queries with strings, there's too much scope for mistakes, but I like being able to have my agg queries in json. I think I might look at parsing it into a BsonDocument() and modifying the object model rather than string.replace() and then parsing into a BsonDocument().